# Difference between bug and failure

Tags: terminology

I want to ask about the difference between bug and failure and error, i read that the error is mistake made by people, but i conflicted between the difference between the bug and failure. I can't know the difference exactly. Can any one help please and give simple snippet for code represents the difference.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I made and ***error*** by introducing a ***bug*** in the program code that resulted in a ***failure*** of the whole software...

Comment: I thought people were debating "Glitch vs Bug"

Answer (score 4):

- **Bug is a programming error** - not checking array bounds, ignoring error codes, multiple deletions, memory leaks, etc. fall under this general category. Errors like this require code changes to fix (there may be *work-arounds* that do not require code changes, though)
- **Failure is a system error** - disconnection of storage, lack of network connectivity, and hardware failures are in this category. Fixing failures usually requires configuring other parts of the system, not the program itself.
- **User errors are mistakes made by users** - entering values incorrectly or providing incomplete data are in this category. Errors like that are fixed by the user who uses the program without anyone else's involvement.

Answer (score 1):

By my definition I would say

- An **error** is about my behavior, or my acting. so I **make** errors.
- A **bug** is the the result of my error in the program code.
- The **failure** is the **malfunction** of my buggy software.

but others may interpret this differently.

Answer (score 1):

A **fault** or **Bug** is a defect within the system (Somewhere hidden in the code and maybe never detected!).

An **error** is a deviation of the required operation of the system or subsystem. (The fault detected during execution but no harm).

A **failure** occurs when the system fails to perform its required function. (System crash)

An **Error** is a manifestation of a **fault** in a system, which could lead to system **failure**.

(Singhal/Shivaratri)

Example:

If you multiply x with 4 instead of 2 in your code, but there is no way to affect any functionalists or is not visible. This is a bug or fault. 
If user can see it, let's say with having a wrong text as subject of email, then this is an error but still system worked and no harmful event happened. 
But if your system withdraw the wrong money to user in a bank or your robot cut the head of the lady instead of cutting the cake for her then this is a failure :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of code snippets, I gave your examples below. I hope examples help you to understand the term better.

Bug is a term used among testers to address faults in software.

Error is a value or state or operation that is varies from expected value or state or operation. For example, programmer makes a mistake like missing a semi-colon, calling a wrong function name.

> Result from system != Expected Result from system

Fault is a error brought into a system during design or implementation stage that is capable of causing system failure. Imagine some company X gives discount to their loyal customer. Loyal customer is someone who shops 10 times in a month. In software, programmer enter 20 times instead of 10. This is a mistake introduced by programmer called error. then it turned  to fault. In tester language, it is a bug.

System failure is an inability of a system to do, what is required of the system. For example, if a user tries to sign up for account in a social networking site if they site fails to register the user. Then, that is system failure.

Technically,

> Error -----> Fault -----> Failure

The root cause of any failure is error.